# Weird Wifi Issue on Mac - some websites don't work if typed into address bar, but can be accessed otherwise

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, connection

I have a really peculiar issue that I've been having at my parents' home wi-fi. At my house, all websites work without issue. However, on only my computer, if I type in google.com, I get "No data received ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" on Chrome. However, if I use the google search in the address bar, it loads fine. Most other websites work fine, some notable examples are Google, Youtube, and Wikipedia. This issue also occurs on Safari, but when I logged into my laptop as a guest, Google worked fine. So in summary:

- Some websites don't work if I type them into the address bar, but can
  be accessed through links or built in search bars
- This only occurs on my laptop, other users in the house don't have
  this issue, and only on this specific Wi-Fi network, other networks
  don't cause this issue
- The guest account can access the problem websites

This has been an issue for quite some time but I'm never at my parents home long enough to try to troubleshoot it because the issue is seemingly random. Any insight?

Comment: Have you configured custom DNS servers or are you using the default ones?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue at home with Comcast. Some sites loaded but others timed out as you described. I added public Google's DNS hosts (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) to my router's DHCP config settings and this resolved the issue for me